# Using Facebook API in Swift. "App ID not found"?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-3.1

I filled the keys in info.plist according the Facebook's Tutorial, but when I try my application, the following exception message is shown:

'InvalidOperationException', reason: 'App ID not found. Add a string value with your app ID for the key FacebookAppID to the Info.plist or call [FBSDKSettings setAppID:].'

I just checked the App Id, and it's right, and I really don't know the reason of this error. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might have given FacebookAppId instead of FacebookAppID...

Comment: what if it's not that?

Comment: How this could be an excepted answer?

Comment: matlab kucch bhi

Comment: anyone has a better answer to that error?